# Make a chrome extension that refreshes page once as soon as url changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a javascript newbie and I have been struggling lately to build this chrome extension but I haven’t had any luck to make it work.

Basically I want a chrome extension that Refreshes page **ONCE** as soon as URL changes "let's say I clicked on a video or hit the search button". And I want it to run on all tabs that are in youtube.com website. Is there any way to make this happen ?

Here is my manifest.json :

```
{
"name": "Youtube Refresh",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Youtube Refresh",
"permissions": [
"storage",
"tabs",
"activeTab",
"storage",
"<all_urls>",
"tabs",
"webNavigation",
"browsingData",
"notifications",
"cookies",
"management",
"alarms"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": 
    [ "*://www.youtube.com/*" ],
    "js": [ "contentscript.js" ],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_start"
    }
], 
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

And yes I gave the extension loads of unnecessary permissions so I make sure that it wouldn't be the issue.

And here is my contentscript.js :

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e){

if(!window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
    window.location.reload();
}

});
```

I expect a lot of issues with this code but I tried every thing possible but it just would't run.

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952) and [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)